# Why my data are duplicating? (ASP.Net Mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try learning something in Asp net Mvc, but I have a trouble.
I wish my data were not duplicated when I start the program every time.
I thought that it will be working fine and my data will create while first run. Why does not work it?

Store Context:

```
namespace StoreProject.DAL
{
    using StoreProject.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;

    public class StoreContext : DbContext
    {
        public StoreContext()
            : base("name=StoreDb")
        {
        }
        static StoreContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<StoreContext>(new StoreInitializer());
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Storeinitializer:

```
namespace StoreProject.DAL
{
    public class StoreInitializer : MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<StoreContext, Configuration>
    {
        public static void SeedStoreData(StoreContext context)
        {
            var products = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product(){Name = "Chockolate1",Price = 2.20f, Country = "Russia"},
                new Product(){Name = "Chockolate2", Price=3.30f, Country = "Poland"},

            };
            products.ForEach(a => context.Products.AddOrUpdate(a));

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Configuration in Migrations folder

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using StoreProject.DAL;
using StoreProject.Models;

namespace StoreProject.Migrations
{

    public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<StoreProject.DAL.StoreContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            ContextKey = "StoreProject.DAL.StoreContext";
        }

        protected override void Seed(StoreProject.DAL.StoreContext context)
        {
            StoreInitializer.SeedStoreData(context);


            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not giving it a key/key combo to compare against so everything you pass in is an Add operation as far as it is concerned.

```
products.ForEach(product => context.Products.AddOrUpdate(p => new {p.Name, p.Country},  product));
```

Comment: Fine it works. This is what I ment. I think so now that maybe better is add a new migration and in "up" method type sql code which will insert a new data. What do you think about it? Ps. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Honestly...I personally belief DB First approach is only worth using in proof of concept scenarios. It's really cool but I've never seen it end well when it is scaled out to a team or run in any amount of time in a production environment. Something or someone always tends to muck up the settings and that can be insanely scary if you are rapidly deploying. Not to mention it really locks out your DB members if you are lucky to have them. I just don't trust DB First enough to even have a valid opinion on best practices or guidance. Wish I could be more help...